# jQuery Waypoints - functions seem to be overriding each other

Tags: jquery, function

this is my first post here on StackOverflow. I can't seem to find an answer for a problem I've got with jQuery Waypoints.
(I'm quite new to coding so excuse me if this has a simple solution).

Basically I've got a one page site with 5 sections on it which look like individual pages. I coded it so that when you reach the top of each page the HTML  of the page is changed through jQuery. Then when you get down closer towards the bottom on that section, the content on the next section below fades in. This all works fine. However, when I'm scrolling back up, the HTML  of the page changes NOT when I'm at the top of the section, but near the bottom (so the point which makes the content on the next page fade in). What more is that it seems to be changing it to the title of the previous page, not the current one.

Have a look at this link to see what I mean:  http://lovecolour.co.nz/uploader/site1/index.html

Scroll down to the orange Branding section. Then scroll back up,  and watch what happens to the HTML Page Title as you scroll past the white dotted line on the bottom.

Basially it appears to me like it works fine for when you're going down (title changes when you reach the top of the page, content fades in when you reach the near-bottom of that page). However when you're going back up the latter function is overriding the first, so the Title is changing near the dotted line rather than top of the page.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$("#digital .spacer").css({opacity:0})
$("#branding .spacer").css({opacity:0});
$("#print .spacer").css({opacity:0});
$("#about .spacer").css({opacity:0});

$("#clickToSee").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("#digital .spacer").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
    }
    else {
    $("#digital .spacer").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
    }
});

$("#bLineDigital").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("#branding .spacer").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
    }
    else {
        $("#branding .spacer").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
    }
});

$("#branding .dottedBottom").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("#print .spacer").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
    }
    else {
        $("#print .spacer").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
    }
});

$("#print .dottedBottom").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("#about .spacer").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
    }
    else {
        $("#about .spacer").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
    }
});

$("#digital").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("title").html("Digital");
    }
    else {
        $("title").html("LoveColour");
    }
});

$("#branding").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("title").html("Branding");
    }
    else {
        $("title").html("Digital");
    }
});
$("#print").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("title").html("Print");
    }
    else {
        $("title").html("Branding");
    }
});
$("#about").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "down") {
    $("title").html("About LoveColour");
    }
    else {
        $("title").html("Print");
    }
});
```

I would appreciate all the help I could get - I hope everything is clear. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints uses an event (`waypoint.reached`) to fire the callbacks.  Events bubble in JavaScript. So if you have nested waypoints, like how `#bLineDigital` is a descendant of `#digital`, hitting the nested waypoint will bubble that event and also trigger the outer one. You just have to stop the bubbling. `event.stopPropagation()` within the nested handlers will do the trick.

Comment: What a legend! That was the exact fix I was after, thank you!